# The first card of my React Bootstrap's accordion does not open

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm building a basic bike list app. I want to hide the bike's details inside an accordion and load them only when the user open the bike's card. It's working for all the element except the first one.

To do so i write the following code:

```
return data.bikes.map((bike, index) => {
    return(
      <Card key={index} onClick={(e) => {this.setState({selected: bike.id});}}>
        <Card.Header>
          <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey={index}>
            {bike.title}, {index}
          </Accordion.Toggle>
        </Card.Header>
        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={index}>
          <Card.Body>
            Bike Details:
            <BikeDetails bikeId={this.state.selected}/>
          </Card.Body>
        </Accordion.Collapse>
      </Card>
    )
  });
```

To make the first element open I change my code like this:

```
  return data.bikes.map((bike, index) => {
    return(
      <Card key={index+1} onClick={(e) => {this.setState({selected: bike.id});}}>
        <Card.Header>
          <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey={index+1}>
            {bike.title}, {index}, {index+1}
          </Accordion.Toggle>
        </Card.Header>
        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={index+1}>
          <Card.Body>
            Bike Details:
            <BikeDetails bikeId={this.state.selected}/>
          </Card.Body>
        </Accordion.Collapse>
      </Card>
    )
  });
```

And now the first element open correctly but I'm not quite happy with this solution.
I would like to know if there is a better way of doing it.

CodeSandbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-pond-v5y2y?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: can you provide a working codesandbox link?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-pond-v5y2y?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: In your eventKey property, instead of index, provide bike.id. That should work

Comment: From what I understood, eventKey doesn't accept 0 as a valid value. But it supports '0'. So when you provided 0 index, it didn't toggle the accordian

Comment: Seems weird, but it works

Comment: Can you please upvote the answer if it helped you ! Thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't have enough reputation for now sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer by [Chandradeepta Laha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11867431/chandradeepta-laha) :

> In your eventKey property, instead of index, provide bike.id. That should work

Answer (score 3):

The better solution is to assign `bike.id` to eventKey because you already assigning the `index` to Card key as unique key for every card. it work perfect this way.

```
return data.bikes.map((bike, index) => {
    return(
      <Card key={index} onClick={(e) => {this.setState({selected: bike.id});}}>
        <Card.Header>
          <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey={bike.id}>
            {bike.title}, {index}
          </Accordion.Toggle>
        </Card.Header>
        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={bike.id}>
          <Card.Body>
            Bike Details:
            <BikeDetails bikeId={this.state.selected}/>
          </Card.Body>
        </Accordion.Collapse>
      </Card>
    )
  });
```